# Edittext on background fragment still editable

Tags: android, background, android-edittext

I have problem with using EditText with several fragments. I have two fragments: FragmentOne and FragmentTwo, and each fragment has EditText.
After adding FragmentTwo above FragmentOne:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame,new FragmentTwo()).addToBackStack(null).commit;
```

When I press Enter on keyboard, cursor goes to EditText on FragmentOne. How to fix it? Similar problem was when background fragment was still clickable, but I've solved it. What about this problem?

Comment: You can try to make first EditText view unfocusable/disable, before you add new fragment and revert it, when you return to Fragment One.

Comment: is there any other way, i.e on XML of layout? For example, on case of clickable background I've used android:clickable="true" on xml layout file.

Comment: You can't define logic in XML file, but you can change view properties programmatically. XML layout is used only for create view hierarchy, but then you have an access to this hierarchy from Java code - those two scopes are separated. Eventually other idea which I've you can setOnEditorActionListener on both views and override scenario, when user click enter to not move focus to other edittext view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is becauase, you are not hiding/removing the previous fragment. identify the previousfragment and hide it before you add the new one.

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame,new FragmentTwo()).addToBackStack(null).commit;
```

this should be

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.frame,new FragmentTwo()).hide([current fragment]).addToBackStack(null).commit;
```

if you gave a name to your fragment, you can find the fragment by

```
fragmentManager.findFragmentByName("fragname");
```

Comment: will previous fragment show automatically when I call popUpBackStackImmideately() ?

Comment: This works. Also, I noticed a white flash when the transaction happens(with animation enabled) any way to remove this white flash?

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this issue as well. I have a parent fragment and I show and hide a child fragment. There is an editText in the parent fragment which ends up in the back of the child fragment. At the time of displaying the child fragment I went into the fragment layout and set its view to gone, and that removed the focus. Of course if I were to hide the child fragment, then the layout would be visible again.